# "Instant alpha" function in iPhone app

Tags: iphone

Is there anything in the SDK which would allow you to replicate the instant alpha functionality found in some mac apps (Pages, Keynote, Preview) on the iPhone?

Basically my objective is to take a picture which contains a main object against a fairly even background, and eliminate the background leaving only the main object. The user could select the areas that represent the background. As an example, from this original: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOgvn.jpg

We would get this image after applying the effect (white background is transparent): https://i.stack.imgur.com/McGwA.png

Answer (score 1):

In the SDK, no. You'd have to loop through every pixel and check it's color and see if it is within some threshold you have specified.